# how to attach on to the `onclick` event of the link? (autocomplete)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Do autocomple. Need in the dropdown prompts to make links.

I use this [plugin](https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/auto-complete/demo.html).

```
$(function () {
    $('input[name="oem"]').autoComplete({
        minChars: 4,
        source: function (term, response) {
            term = term.toLowerCase();
            $.getJSON('/search.json?oem=' + term, function (data) {
                var matches = [];
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                    if (~data[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(term))
                        matches.push(data[i]);
                response(matches.slice(0, 11));
            });
        },
        renderItem: function (item, search) {
            search = search.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g);
            var re = new RegExp("(" + search.split(' ').join('|') + ")");
            return '<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-val="' + item + '"><a href="#" onclick="javascript:document.location.href="#"">' + item.replace(re, "<b>$1</b>") + '</a></div>';
        }
    });
});
```

How to attach on to the `onclick` event of the link?
Are there other variants?

Answer (score 0):

You can put class on your dynamically generated `<a></a>` tags inside `renderItem` function, for example `class="dynamically-added"` and then attach event handler to document that is listening for clicked item of this class. Check this demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  // This is how you can handle click event of dynamically added elements via jQuery
  $(document).on('click', '.dynamically-added', function(){
    console.log('clicked -> ' + $(this).text());
  });
  
  var container = $('#container');
  
  for(var i=1; i < 6; i++){
    container.append('<a href="#" class="dynamically-added">Dynamically added '+i+'</a><br/>');
  } 
  
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  
</div>
```

**EDIT**

So your code will look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // This is the event handler code
    $(document).on('click', '.dynamically-added', function () {
        console.log('clicked -> ' + $(this).text());
    });

    $('input[name="oem"]').autoComplete({
        minChars: 4,
        source: function (term, response) {
            term = term.toLowerCase();
            $.getJSON('/search.json?oem=' + term, function (data) {
                var matches = [];
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                    if (~data[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(term))
                        matches.push(data[i]);
                response(matches.slice(0, 11));
            });
        },
        renderItem: function (item, search) {
            search = search.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g);
            var re = new RegExp("(" + search.split(' ').join('|') + ")");
            // Here check your <a> I added class="dynamically-added"
            return '<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-val="' + item + '"><a href="#" class="dynamically-added">' + item.replace(re, "<b>$1</b>") + '</a></div>';
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: i added `.dynamically-added`, but message does not appear. Help to implement in code

Comment: Hello mate, you need to use the three lines of code under **// This is how you can handle click event of dynamically added elements via jQuery** to handle your click events

Comment: put this in `renerItem`? in the console, no messages.

Comment: @dmitriy check the **EDIT**, this is how your code should look like, please try to understand how does it work and when you have questions try searching in google first. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Below, I have changed the way you are building the return string in your code,

`return "<div class='autocomplete-suggestion' data-val='" + item + "'><a href='#' onclick='javascript:document.location.href="+\""+"#"+\""+">" + item.replace(re, "<b>$1</b>") + "</a></div>";`

Comment: variant with `javascript:document.location.href` not working